# Synchronized in typescript angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code.

```js
public async getOrderInforAsync(customerOrderId) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.orderEntryService.getCommissionIncentives(customerOrderId)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            Object.assign(this.order, response);
            this.order.bookingDate = this.order.bookingDate ? new Date(this.order.bookingDate) : null;
            this.order.estBillDate = this.order.estBillDate ? new Date(this.order.estBillDate) : null;
            this.order.orderSplit.forEach(element => {
              element.rcNumberFullName = `${this.order.customerOrderRCNumber}${element.rcNumberSuffix}`;
            });
            this.initialQuantityAllocated();
            this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent = this.calculateTotalOrderPercent();
            this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount = this.calculateTotalOrderAmount();
            this.highlight = this.checkOrderSummary(this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent, this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount);
            this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent();
            this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount();
            this.onChangeEstSalesPrice();
            resolve();
          },
          error => {
            reject();
          }
        );
    });
}
```

Sometimes the resolve() is called before this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent() and this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount() are done.
So how to make this code run synchronized, it means all functions on this block code had done before resolve() called?

Comment: Are `this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent()` and `this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount()` asynchronous in nature? Do they make any API calls or something? If not, then this code should run synchronously.

Comment: Hi SiddAjmera, this function is called from other function with other API, so I want to this code done before another function call.

Comment: @PHONGDN, do `this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent()` and `this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount()` return `Promise`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera No, its just normal function.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function returns a `Promise`. And to declare a function as `async`, you need to have an `await` call inside it.

Change your observable returned from `this.orderEntryService.getCommissionIncentives(customerOrderId)` `.toPromise()` and then `await` it.

Try this:

```
public async getOrderInforAsync(customerOrderId) {

  try {
    const response = await this.orderEntryService
      .getCommissionIncentives(customerOrderId).toPromise();

    this.order = { ...response };
    this.order.bookingDate = this.order.bookingDate ? new Date(this.order.bookingDate) : null;
    this.order.estBillDate = this.order.estBillDate ? new Date(this.order.estBillDate) : null;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.order.orderSplit; i++) {
      const element = this.order.orderSplit[i];
      element.rcNumberFullName = `${this.order.customerOrderRCNumber}${element.rcNumberSuffix}`
    }
    this.initialQuantityAllocated();
    this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent = this.calculateTotalOrderPercent();
    this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount = this.calculateTotalOrderAmount();
    this.highlight = this.checkOrderSummary(this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent, this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount);
    this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent();
    this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount();
    this.onChangeEstSalesPrice();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: exportPDF() {
 this.reviewComponent.getOrderInforAsync().then(() => {
  this.export();
 });
}

my code in other components. I want to all functions are done to binding all html, then export from html to pdf. But sometimes some function in the question block not done yet. So html is generated not enough.

Comment: @PHONGDN, that would mean that apart from the call to the `this.orderEntryService.getCommissionIncentives(customerOrderId)` method, there's another asynchronous call in the `getOrderInforAsync` method. But you said that there isn't any. So you might want to shed some light on that. May be create a sample stackblitz, replicating your issue.

Comment: @SiddAjmere Export pdf call getOrderInforAsync() --> render html --> after that call exportPDF().  "May be create a sample stackblitz, replicating your issue" My product is quiet big so maybe I cannot create another review code like stackblitz for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public async getOrderInforAsync(customerOrderId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.orderEntryService.getCommissionIncentives(customerOrderId)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            Object.assign(this.order, response);
            this.order.bookingDate = this.order.bookingDate ? new Date(this.order.bookingDate) : null;
            this.order.estBillDate = this.order.estBillDate ? new Date(this.order.estBillDate) : null;
            this.order.orderSplit.forEach(element => {
              element.rcNumberFullName = `${this.order.customerOrderRCNumber}${element.rcNumberSuffix}`;
            });
            this.initialQuantityAllocated();
            this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent = this.calculateTotalOrderPercent();
            this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount = this.calculateTotalOrderAmount();
            this.highlight = this.checkOrderSummary(this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionPercent, this.orderSummary.allocatedEstCommissionAmount);
            await this.calculateAllocatedActualPercent();
            await this.calculateAllocatedActualAmount();
            this.onChangeEstSalesPrice();
            resolve();
          },
          error => {
            reject();
          }
        );
    });
}

async calculateAllocatedActualPercent(){
  return new Promise(resolve,reject){
    // call api 
    if (data)
      resolve(data);
    else 
      reject()
  }
}

async calculateAllocatedActualAmount(){
  return new Promise(resolve,reject){
    // call api 
    if (data)
      resolve(data);
    else 
      reject()
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, `forEach` won't work in an `async` function. You'll have to change it to a regular `for` loop. Also, as the OP commented, the `calculateAllocatedActualPercent` and `calculateAllocatedActualAmount` are normal functions and don't return a `Promise`.

Comment: @Sarthak Aggarwal, I wanna resolve(); is called last because i have this code


exportReviewPdf() {
  getOrderInforAsync().then(() =>{
   export();
}
}

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thanks! I didn't know that. But just to clear up, `forEach` doesn't work if i have async code inside `forEach`, but we can have `forEach` inside a `async` call?

Comment: @PHONGDN can you share `exportReviewPdf()` and where do you call it?

Comment: I call this function after edit order and auto export pdf.